# Testing a website in Steam overlay webbrowser

Tags: steam, browser

How do I test my website in Steam overlay webbrowser without running a game?

Comment: Why "without running a game"?

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 because I want to test a website, not launch an unrelated game just to open the overlay browser.

Comment: @Abyx That's like asking "How do I test cheats without launching the game"... The steam overlay is tied to playing games you cannot open it without playing a game. If opening a game is such a hassle why not buy a small cheap (or even free) game that boots really fast just so you can test the overlay?

Comment: Curious - Why do you want to test your website in the overlay? And how is it game dev related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't quite address "without running a game", but a useful "placeholder game" for this kind of thing is [Spacewar, which is the Steamworks API tutorial](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/sdk/api/example).

To install/launch it, run "steam://run/480" from the Run dialog (Windows-R)

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm not Steam dev, so I can't speak to this with much authority. I also suspect that the NDAs of SteamWorks may prevent those who do know from providing definitive, on the record answers. If you yourself are already a Steam dev, I'd recommend contacting them to see if there's some manner of pre launch support that might fit your needs.

That being said, I was able to do a little bit of work to make some educated guesses.  Here's a sample dump of `GameOverlayUI.exe.log` when running a game:

```
Thu Nov 09 21:29:33 2017 UTC - GameOverlay process started: pid: 9504
Thu Nov 09 21:29:33 2017 UTC - GameOverlay process connecting to: pid: 11112
Thu Nov 09 21:29:34 2017 UTC - BuildID: 1509425745
Thu Nov 09 21:29:34 2017 UTC - Steam Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam
Thu Nov 09 21:29:39 2017 UTC - SetScreenSize( 1253, 635 )
Thu Nov 09 21:29:39 2017 UTC - Changing resolutions from (1280, 1024) -> (1253, 635)
Thu Nov 09 21:29:40 2017 UTC - Generating new string page texture 2739: 256x256, total string texture memory is 262.14 KB
Thu Nov 09 21:29:40 2017 UTC - Generating new string page texture 2740: 128x256, total string texture memory is 393.22 KB
Thu Nov 09 21:29:41 2017 UTC - Overlay enable requested by game
```

Here's what happens if I attempt to manually launch the overlay:

```
Thu Nov 09 21:34:21 2017 UTC - GameOverlay process started: pid: 9128
Thu Nov 09 21:34:21 2017 UTC - GameOverlay exiting due to missing PID argument
```

I get the latter even when running a non-Steam game that I've added to my library. So it looks like GameOverlayUI won't launch if it can't handshake with an actual Steam app. Barring an official solution, I suspect the best you might be able to do is build a mock app of some kind that completes the handshake & go from there. Alternatively, there might be some command line switch that allows the overlay to function without the handshake - if such a thing exists, again you probably need to sign the NDA to know about it. Maybe you could fuzz it out, but that likely breaks their TOS.

Answer (score 0):

The steam client uses a version of Chromium to display the websites. There shouldn't be too many differences between that and Chrome.

Comment: Actually there're many important differences.

Comment: @Abyx Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Events, mostly. Right-click always shows menu, no MouseEvent.movementX/Y.